# Can the Mac version of Adobe Lightroom 3 automatically create smart-collections for camera, lenses, date, etc.?

Tags: lightroom, software, adobe, smart-collections

I just installed Lightroom 3 on my Mac when I discovered that the license I had for it was valid for both Mac and Windows.

I seem to remember, but could be wrong, that Lightroom could/would create collections or whatnot that grouped photos by the lens I used, the camera I used, as well as by the date they were taken, but here I only have the Folders-view, which shows all the photos grouped by how they are organized on disk.

I can of course create smart collections for whatever, but I seem to recall that Lightroom 3 on Windows created lots of these smart collections by itself. In other words, what I remember is that if I took a photo with a new camera, a new lens, in a new month, a new year, and then imported that photo, Lightroom would add the required nodes in a tree-based collection.

Note that I know I can pull down the filter bar, and it shows all the things there if I pick the metadata filter, but I remember that I had the same kind of stuff in the left hand panel, under the Navigator and Catalog sections, that I also had some kind of browser there that automatically grouped by the same things. However, the thing I remember was found in the left hand navigator pane, down below the folder view, I don't remember where it was in comparison to the Collections section.

Am I remembering wrong?

If not, does this function, ie. group by camera, lens, date, other types of metadata, exist in the Mac version?

If it does, how do I turn it on? I've scoured the catalog preferences and the program preferences and the view menu, but I can't find anything that matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're correct: what you're describing are Lightroom **Collections**. You'll see the Collections pane in the left-hand panel, usually at or near the bottom (depending on which module you're in: in the Library module it's below Folders). If it's not there, just right-click on the left-hand panel and make sure Collections is ticked. You may have to scroll down (or close the other panes) to see it.

Collections are a way of building up virtual sets of photos without having to physically relocate them on disk. They come in two flavours: regular Collections, and **Smart Collections**. (If you're used to using iTunes, a useful analogy is with Playlists and Smart Playlists.) With a regular collection, you drag photos onto it to add them. When you create a smart collection you specify a set of criteria to match and photos then automatically appear in the collection if they match the criteria.

To create a new collection, just click the little **+** icon in the Collections pane header and choose either **Create Collection...** or **Create Smart Collection...**.

The set of criteria you can use for smart collections is extensive and very versatile. Using the filters at the top of the Library module's grid view is a good way of filtering the current folder, but smart collections allow you to apply similar filtering across your entire catalog.

Comment: Sorry, there seems to have been some unclarity in my question, my apologies. What I remember is that Lightroom created a tree-based date-organized, camera-organized, lense-organized, etc. collection-view automatically. I have the Collections section, and can easily create all the virtual collections I want, but I seem to remember that Lightroom had some basic smart collections for dates, lenses, cameras, etc. automatically built in. So that I don't have to keep adding new smart collections for years and months, or new cameras, manually. I guess maybe I remember wrong then.

Comment: p.s. Just to help clarify the terminology a little: the **catalog** is your complete set of photos managed by Lightroom. It is possible to have multiple catalogs, although many people just have one. **Collections** are as I've described above and it's typical to have plenty of them. There's no such thing as a "smart catalog" but I'm sure smart collections are what you were referring to.

Comment: Yes, sorry :P Smart collections.

Comment: Oh, sorry Lasse, I understand now. Actually that sounds familiar to me too but when I check in my Lightroom they're not there either. Maybe we've both deleted them or imagined it? :) It would be very easy to re-create such collections though.

Comment: I think I will try to spin up my old machine and check the Lightroom installation. It requires some work, but I think it might be worth it. Perhaps it was a feature of Lightroom 2 or 1, and was replaced with the filter pane in 3, I dunno. Anyway, after I find out what is in my old Lightroom 3 on Windows, I'll come back here.

Comment: Great, I'll be interested to hear how you get on. The filter panel has always been there since LR1, btw. This site lists some basic default smart collections that look familiar: http://www.photokaboom.com/photography/learn/Lightroom/d_library_module/5_library_panels_left.htm#Smart

Comment: You were right that the collections section is what there is. I fired up my old machine and it looks exactly the same, so I must be remembering wrong.